# JTable Graphics not updating while adding rows to a DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, event-dispatch-thread

I have this cute problem with my prog (i'm a noob in this) i want to give my prog some animation and i want the divider in the split panel to move from gbPanel.getHeight()(MAX height) to Border.getHeight() (Min height) using the table row leght of 16 pixels if i do a System.out.println to the variables the program seem to work wonders BUT! the table the divider and EVERYthing waits till the while ends to show it self in the window... my 1st try to solve it or at least check if thats the cause was to add a Thread.sleep but that just made the program wait a LOT before the while ends and the window is updated. Then i tried forcing the window to update inside the while but that didnt work either. Anyone mind helping me?

```
/* this display one row of data and makes the splitpanel divider -16 with each row */
public void DespliegaTD() {
DefaultTableModel jModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    jTable1.setModel(jModel);
    jModel.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"Num","Tarjeta","Cuenta","Fecha Trx","Monto","Descripción","Tipo POS","Cod Resp", "Moneda","Autorización","MCC","Resultado"});

    try {
        ResultSet rs = Query(tDebito.getText(),cuenta.getText(),fechaInicio.getText(),fechaFinal.getText());
        while (rs.next()){
            if ((dbPane.getHeight()-(rs.getRow()*jTable1.getRowHeight())) >= (Border.getHeight()-1)) 
                dbPane.setDividerLocation((dbPane.getHeight()-(rs.getRow()*jTable1.getRowHeight())));
            jModel.addRow(new Object[] {rs.getRow(),rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),dateFormat4.format(dateFormat3.parse(rs.getString(3))),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8),rs.getString(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getString(11)});
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BVtarjetas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BVtarjetas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

Comment: What in tarnation is a "JMODEL"?

Comment: Please use accurate language if you want to communicate accurate information. Your title is very confusing since there is no entity known as a "JModel". Use "TableModel" or "DefaultTableModel" so as not to confuse others looking at just the title, since that is all that shows when searching this site. And yes, that *will* help if you follow the advice.

Comment: Question title changed.

Comment: well pal this time you explained your point and at the same time helped me understand what was wrong with my title the previous time only worked to try to be funny but ende up wasting time and getting ya mad :) next time be helpefull like now and things will be better forma everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is one of trying to do animation in a long-running process on the Swing event thread (aka Event Dispatch Thread or EDT). The solution is to use a background thread such as via a SwingWorker.

Comment: Thanks i will try to get info about the SwingWorker thing and check TVE revalidate as repaint didnt work when i tried yesterday

Comment: +1 for the SwingWorker, but I don't see any reason for doing a revalidate() or repaint() on the table. Updating the model will cause the table to repaint automatically.

Comment: He is playing with the divider location of the split pane as each row is read to continually display one more row in the split pane. Setting the divider location will invoke revalidate and repaint. No components are being added or removed.

Comment: @camickr: OK. I will remove the recommendation. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Learning how to get the swingworker to work with my prog... i found lots of mistakes it seems NetBeans can run programs well but once they are inside the jar nothing works, i used relative positions in all the images yet inside the jar none worked :/ the way im setting the divider doesnt work well with swing worker because it returns control to the prog and i still don hace the data to do anything so i will try implenting a progresa bar to wait for the table data to be retrieved do The calculations and see how it works

Comment: as hoverCraft pointed SwingWorker did the job :D, better than i even spected.